# Imacros условия проверки на наличие нового фрейма

Tags: imacros

```
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
FRAME F=1
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Инструменты
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:О****<SP>на<SP>****
FRAME F=2
TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Атаковать
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG SELECTOR="#battle__button__position_attack"
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG SELECTOR="#battle__button__position_attack"
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG SELECTOR="#battle__button__position_attack"
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG SELECTOR="#battle__button__position_attack"
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG SELECTOR="#battle__button__position_attack"
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG SELECTOR="#battle__button__position_attack"
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG SELECTOR="#battle__button__position_attack"
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG SELECTOR="#battle__button__position_attack"
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG SELECTOR="#battle__button__position_attack"
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG SELECTOR="#battle__button__position_attack"
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG SELECTOR="#battle__button__position_attack"
WAIT SECONDS=3
TAG SELECTOR="#battle__button__position_attack"
TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Выйти<SP>из<SP>боя
```

Фреймы которые могут возникать при окончания боя (`TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Выйти<SP>из<SP>боя`) или при обновлении боя (`TAG POS=1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:Обновить`), как заставить проверять наличие этих фреймов на текущей странице, она динамически менятся по окончанию боя или же возникает кнопка обновить.

Frames that can occur when the battle ends TAG POS = 1 TYPE = A ATTR = TXT: Exit < SP > from the < SP > battle or when the battle is updated (TAG POS = 1 TYPE = A ATTR = TXT: Update), how to force check for these frames on the current page, it changes dynamically at the end of the battle or the refresh button appears